# SSH keygen error: 'passphrase too short: have 2 bytes, need >4'

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to automate the process of generating an SSH RSA key.When the command below is run on the command line it generates the key correctly:

```
ssh-keygen -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
```

The issue arises when I try to replicate this in a python 2 script.

```
 if not os.path.isfile('/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'):
    fullcmd = ['ssh-keygen', '-f', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa', '-t', 'rsa', '-N', '\'\'']
    sshcmd = subprocess.Popen(fullcmd,
                shell= False,
                stdout= subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr= subprocess.STDOUT)
    out = sshcmd.communicate()[0].split('\n')
    for lin in out:
        print lin
```

When I run this script I get this error:

```
> passphrase too short: have 2 bytes, need >4
> Generating public/private
> rsa key pair. Saving the key failed: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

Why dose it work when I execute it on the command line and not through the python script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fullcmd = ['ssh-keygen', '-f', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa', '-t', 'rsa', '-N', '\'\'']
```

`''` is shell syntax for passing an empty string. You're invoking the command directly, not via a shell, so don't pass single quotes. Just pass the empty string itself.

```
fullcmd = ['ssh-keygen', '-f', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa', '-t', 'rsa', '-N', '']
```